# Google CalDAV background sync'ing?

Tags: sync, google-calendar, calendar.app, caldav

I currently use MobileMe to sync my calendars between my Macs and iPhone.  I'm thinking about switching to Google's CalDAV, but I'm not sure if the calendars will be updated if iCal on my Mac or the calendar app on my iPhone isn't running.  In other words, will it do background sync'ing?

I know about the other services like Spanning Sync and BusyCal, but the whole point in going CalDAV is to get something free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, CalDAV in iCal requires you to open the application for it to sync.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the Mac, but CalDAV calendars on the iPhone are synced in the background.

You can specify how often this occurs by going to **Settings->Mail,Contacts,Calendar->Fetch New Data**. From that menu if you go into the **Advanced** menu you can specify which of your calendars will be automatically synced by setting them to 'Fetch'.

Comment: I think on the Mac side, I'm going to have to use something like BusySync:  http://www.busymac.com.  On the iPhone, I have to turn on Fetch to use CalDAV in the background, which makes sense.  I'm not sure which affects battery life more, fetch or activesync.

Comment: Reports seem to be mixed on battery life, but I personally found that ActiveSync really churned through my battery (using ~30% of battery life overnight instead of ~5%), so I switched back to an hourly fetch. Battery life is more important to me than instant notification of email.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if anyone's still bothered but one option (which I've just done, because I couldn't find any true background sync options) is to remove iCal's dock icon (Dock Dodger), and set it as a startup item.

I've combined this with QuickCal (awesome) and the Google Calendar widget, so I never have to open iCal :-)